# vim: number of total buffers

Tags: vim, buffer

in vim, with

```
:buffers
```

I get the number of all buffers
the same with

```
:ls
```

, but
how I can get the total number of buffers ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Same idea than Heptite's solution, but as a one liner. Many other things may be done this way: get the name of the buffer (thanks to map), [wipeout buffers that match a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155461/how-to-delete-multiple-buffers-in-vim/3156541#3156541), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974192/how-can-i-pare-down-vims-buffer-list-to-only-include-active-buffers/2974600#2974600n etc.

```
echo len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)'))
```

Answer (score 21):

Answers so far are too hacky.  Here is vim's built-in way:

```
len(getbufinfo({'buflisted':1}))
```

As always, see vim's help (`:h getbufinfo()`) for the official explanation.

Comment: At the time this was asked, your answer would not have been possible because Vim didn't support it. Now it's probably the optimal solution.

Comment: Is it possible to get the number in the current tab instead?

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge there is no built-in method in Vim to do this, but you could create a function:

```
function! NrBufs()
    let i = bufnr('$')
    let j = 0
    while i >= 1
        if buflisted(i)
            let j+=1
        endif
        let i-=1
    endwhile
    return j
endfunction
```

Put the above in a text file with its name ending in .vim, :source it, then you can do something like:

```
:let buffer_count = NrBufs()
:echo buffer_count
```

***June 21 note:*** If you have a recent version of Vim as of 2017, Gid's answer below is the optimal solution.

Comment: Note for others who find this: I think it should be 'while i > 0', since buffer numbers start from 1, not 0.

Comment: @Meta: I fixed my answer. Thanks.  Although it's not really going to be an issue since there will always be at least one buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking perhaps for ?

```
:echo(bufnr('$'))
```

Comment: This will "count" buffers that have been unloaded since Vim never recycles a buffer number, plus it would have to be :echo bufnr('$')

Comment: (Okay, your version will properly echo the number of the last loaded buffer, but the syntax is a little confusing.)

Comment: @Heptite - Yes, that was a mistake. As to the matter of syntax, I see no difference between the two.

Comment: They do the same thing, but :echo is a command and not a function, and can never be used like a function (unless you wrap your own user-defined function around an :echo). The difference is important in many contexts of VimL.

Comment: @Heptite - I must admit I've no idea what you just said ... (more of a duct tape engineer here; less of a "code is beautiful" programmer)

Answer (score 2):

If you want Heptite's solution as a command, add the following to your .vimrc file:

```
command BufNum echo len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)'))
```